# How to config HHVM-Fastcgi to support "TLS" "SSL" protocols?

Tags: php, laravel, hhvm

I run HHVM-fastcgi + nginx + Laravel and when i echo stream_get_transports(), "tls" and "ssl" are not present.

Therefore Laravel php  fails with error "stream_socket_enable_crypto" when i try to send mail via SMTP on tls port

How can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stream_socket_enable_crypto` has not been implemented yet in hhvm.

See https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/1647

Answer (score 0):

Just an update on this issue, it has been resolved as of version HHVM version 3.8.   You just need to update your HHVM version.

Run this command if you using Ubuntu...

```
  sudo apt-get upgrade -y hhvm
```